# Undefined index (hid is not being identified)

Tags: php

**On running the following code I'm getting the following error:**

```
Notice: Undefined index: hid in E:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\cont.php

echo "<table align='right'><tr><td><a href='cont.php?hid=101'><input type='button' value='Account Settings'></a></td></tr></table>";
```

**cont.php code:**

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","Rahul","");
    mysql_select_db("ebusiness", $con);

if($_SESSION['id']==1)
    {
 include 'business.php';
}
else if($_GET['hid']==101)
{
    session_start();
     include 'edprofile.php';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are directly checking on `$_GET['hid']` without checking if it is set or not.

```
else if(isset($_GET['hid']) && $_GET['hid'] == 101)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

added :  `$hid  = isset($_GET['hid'])?$_GET['hid']:"";`

edited : `$_GET['hid']` to `else if($hid==101)`

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","Rahul","");
    mysql_select_db("ebusiness", $con);

$hid  = isset($_GET['hid'])?$_GET['hid']:"";

if($_SESSION['id']==1)
    {
 include 'business.php';
}
else if($hid==101)
{
    session_start();
     include 'edprofile.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
else if($_GET['hid']==101)
```

to:

```
else if(isset($_GET['hid']) && $_GET['hid']==101)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that when you are using GET or POST on your page, there is no guarantee that a certain variable has been sent, as the HTTP protocol is stateless by default.

It is there for important to checn that a variable exists, and also that the variable is validated. To this end the isset() method is quite useful. I would recommend you do a

`isset($_GET['hid'])`

in your code in an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

you are also missing to pass hid variable in you get request ( in URL). check it out. It shuld content ?hid=101 or &hid=101 some where.

and replace your else if condition with

```
else if(isset($_GET['hid']) && $_GET['hid']==101)
```